# Update row with values from previous row if null

Tags: sql, database, sybase

Sybase 15 is what I use. 
I have a table which kind of looks like this

```
--------------------------------------------
 Date       |  GroupId  |  Comment
--------------------------------------------
01/05/2012     1              ABC
01/05/2012     2              XYZ
02/05/2012     1              null
02/05/2012     2              null
03/05/2012     1              null
03/05/2012     2              null
04/05/2012     1              DEF
04/05/2012     2              GHI
05/05/2012     1              null
05/05/2012     2              null
06/05/2012     1              null
```

The output I am looking for is as below.
If the comment field is empty/null, update it with value from the previous day (having the same GroupId)

```
-----------------------------------------------
 Date            |  GroupId  |   Comment
-----------------------------------------------
01/05/2012           1              ABC
01/05/2012           2              XYZ
02/05/2012           1              ABC
02/05/2012           2              XYZ
03/05/2012           1              ABC
03/05/2012           2              XYZ
04/05/2012           1              DEF
04/05/2012           2              GHI
05/05/2012           1              DEF
05/05/2012           2              GHI
06/05/2012           1              DEF
```

Comment: When writing a post, if you need to use **lots** of non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) for formatting, chances are you should be using a codeblocks instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tricky one, I assume Sybase does not support `lag()` or `outer apply`.  You could look up all earlier comments in a subquery, and then use a `non exists` clause to demand that there are no comments in-between.  That should find the previous comment.

```
select  Date
,       GroupId
,       case
        when Comment is not null then Comment
        else
        (
        select  Comment
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.GroupId = yt2.GroupId
                and yt2.Comment is not null
                and yt2.Date < yt1.Date
                and not exists
                (
                select  *
                from    YourTable yt3
                where   yt1.GroupId = yt2.GroupId
                        and yt2.Comment is not null
                        and yt3.Date < yt2.Date and yt2.Date < yt1.Date
                )
        ) end as Comment
from    YourTable yt1
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar. That was great help.  The second subquery is missing an and clause yt3.Date != yt2.Date<b>

Comment: You're right, `between` is inclusive!  I've updated the answer